# Django REST framework : IntegrityError at serializers_user_data.owner_id may not be NULL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am following django REST framework tutorial of Authentication & Permissions. As per tutorial i defined models and views buy i am getting the error below:

`IntegrityError at serializers_user_data.owner_id may not be NULL`

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class User_Data(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='user_datas')    
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
    user_city = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user_name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

view.py

```
class User_Mixing():
    queryset = User_Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = User_Data_Serializers
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
        print obj.owner

class User_list(User_Mixing, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    pass

class User_detail(User_Mixing, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    pass
```

Also help me with related_names in foreign key. For what purpose it is used??

Comment: This error indicates that you are trying to save None to user_data.owner field.

Comment: @RajeshKaushik i created a superuser and logged in with that user.. after that i post data .... dont know why this error came.... What are the solution??

Answer (score 1):

I used perform_create method instead of pre_save

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set ipdb in your code

```
    def pre_save(self, obj):
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    obj.owner = self.request.user
    print obj.owner
```

And check the request.user attribute to understand the error.